# Alexa skill rejected as session ends after launchrequest

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I've been searching a lot for help on this but don't find anything that solves my issue.

In summary :
- My skill answers well to launch request, the text is said but session closes even if I have set `shouldEndSession` to false
- My skill answers very well when a user invokes directly the intent.

So my skill is rejected because session ends after `launchRequest`...

JSON sent in response is as follows:

```
{
    "version":"1.0",
    "response":{
        "outputSpeech":{
            "type":"PlainText",
            "text":"Welcome to my skill, how can I help you?"
        },
        "reprompt":{
            "outputSpeech":{
                "type":"PlainText",
                "text":"How can I help you?"
            }
        }
    },
    "shouldEndSession":false
}
```

I don't understand why Alexa closes microphone...

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shouldEndSession` is at a wrong place.

```
{
  "version":"1.0",
  "response":{
    "outputSpeech":{
      "type":"PlainText",
      "text":"Welcome to my skill, how can I help you?"
    },
    "reprompt":{
      "outputSpeech":{
          "type":"PlainText",
          "text":"How can I help you?"
      }
    },
    "shouldEndSession":false
  }
}
```

Comment: My bad... Thanks very much